# rigging mesh deformed

Tags: armature

trying to rig bvh armature to mesh but as you can see makes the mesh severely deformed first I have the armature in rest position then I switch to pose position is there a way to fix this?tried adjusting the bones in edit mode no difference.[image]

[image]

Comment: Note sure with just these two pictures, but this looks like a rotation problem. Try to apply the rotation on your mesh (ctrl+A then rotation)

Comment: Definitely looks like a mesh without rotation + scale being applied. Maybe position, too?